# Show tick on preference screen

Tags: android, preferences, preferencescreen

I have a `PreferenceActivity` with some preference items, and an "account" `PreferenceCategory` that shows the accounts configured in the application. Each account preference is a `PreferenceScreen`, with other options inside. I want to highlight the active account and the question is: is there anyway to show a tick icon (drawable) on the right side of a `PreferenceScreen`? I mean in the `ListView`, not in the detail of the `PreferenceScreen`.

Comment: Do you mean you want a Checkbox in the list?

Comment: @John, no, a CheckBoxPreference isn't what I want because it suggests that you could tick on any item on the list and I only what to highlight one item on that list with a drawable.

Comment: A CheckBoxPreference will only control one item in the list. Other items in the list can be whatever you want them to be e.g. a ListPreference, etc.

Comment: That's correct, but the hightlighted preference hasn't to be clickable nor having checkbox appearance to not confuse the user. Finally I found a solution, that was to built my own custom preference, subclass of "Preference". As I can't respond to my own question, I let the code on a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/kVd4i5VQ, http://pastebin.com/k17fXtqY